# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) Error

Tags: emgucv

I am Beginner in Emgu and I am trying to Build a Program that Controls Mouse by face Movments.i found a Program that Controls Mouse By Face motions in Emgu Examples.But ii work not Correctly and when debugging ends , program shows this error :
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

This Error showed when i was tried to Create a new object of HaarCascade by this instruction :
_face = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

sorry,in can't wrie English well.

Comment: I am also facing same problem and searching for a solution

Comment: If you run your program, for example, compiled as x64 and your Emgu CV dlls which are added as reference to your project are x86, this causes the error you were facing (4 years ago :D).

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV and Emgu runtime requirements are difficult to manage / figure out. The suggested installer script only works with 32 bit windows according to their (Emgu) web page (Anyone run a 32 bit windows these days?). And they only talk about Visual Studio, up to version 2010, two full versions behind current.

That being said, just brute force it.  Try to run a Emgu example, if successful, copy the DLL folder structure exactly from that project into yours.

In my case I ended up adding Emgu.CV, Emgu.Util and Emgu.CV.UI projects to my solution AND copying the X86 and X64 folders full of OpenCV Dlls to my bin/debug folder. Maybe there is a better way, but this worked.